# JSF Primefaces Datatable padding

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I've got a primefaces datatable, and in the last column i have an issue with padding/margin(I believe so)[image: Primeface Datatable with padding issue].

In the column on the right i always have an issue whitespace where i don't want any.
Currently i have a resizeable panel (which is preferable) although i have tried with scrollpanel, outputpanel, outputtext. Can anyone help me remove this whitespace?

relevant code;

```
<p:dataTable
    id="dataTable" 
    value="#{wireTapLogSearch.results}" var="r"
    rendered="#{not empty wireTapLogSearch.results}"
    styleClass="order-table"
    headerClass="order-table-header"
    rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
    align="center"
    columnClasses="idcol, srccol, dstcol, sblcol, flwcol, orddatecol, typcol, xmlcol"
    >



  <p:column style="padding:0 0 0 0!important; margin:0 0 0 0!important;">
    <f:facet name="header">XML Interaction</f:facet>
    <div style="padding:0 0 0 0!important; margin:0 0 0 0!important;">
      <p:panel id="containment" style="width:350px; height:80px; margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0; white-space: pre; overflow: auto;">  
        #{r.XML_INTERACTION}  
      </p:panel>  
      <p:resizable for="containment"/> 
    </div>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

CSS:

> ```
>        .order-table{   
>             border-collapse:collapse;
>             table-layout: fixed;
>             /*width: 80%;*/
>         }
> .order-table-header{
>             text-align:center;
>             background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #E5E5E5;
>             border-bottom:1px solid #BBBBBB;
>             padding:16px;
>         }
> .order-table-odd-row{
>             text-align:center;
>             background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFFF;
>             border-top:1px solid #BBBBBB;
>             padding: 0 0 0 0;
>             margin: 0 0 0 0;
>         }
> .order-table-even-row{
>             text-align:center;
>             background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #F9F9F9;
>             border-top:1px solid #BBBBBB;
>             padding: 0 0 0 0;
>             margin: 0 0 0 0;
>         }
> .preformatted {
>             white-space: pre;
>             overflow: auto;
>             width: 300px;
>         }
> ```

```
        .idcol { width: 30px;}
        .srccol{ width: 20px;}
        .dstcol{ width: 20px;}
        .sblcol{ width: 60px;}
        .flwcol{ width: 60px;}
        .orddatecol{ width: 50px;}
        .typcol{ width: 20px;}
        .xmlcol{
            width: 300px;
            height: 80px;
            white-space: pre;
            overflow: auto;
        }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

*Edit*
Apologies for the delay, only just got our database back up
Generated HTML:

```
<br /><div id="j_id_6:dataTable" class="ui-datatable ui-widget order-table"><table role="grid"><thead><tr role="row"><th id="j_id_6:dataTable:j_id_1u" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c"><span>Wire Tap Log ID</span></div></th><th id="j_id_6:dataTable:j_id_1x" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span>Source Component</span></div></th><th id="j_id_6:dataTable:j_id_20" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span>Destination Component</span></div></th><th id="j_id_6:dataTable:j_id_23" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span>Siebel ID</span></div></th><th id="j_id_6:dataTable:j_id_26" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span>Flow ID</span></div></th><th id="j_id_6:dataTable:j_id_29" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span>Order Date</span></div></th><th id="j_id_6:dataTable:j_id_2c" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span>Type</span></div></th><th id="j_id_6:dataTable:j_id_2f" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" style="padding:0 0 0 0!important; margin:0 0 0 0!important;"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span>XML Interaction</span></div></th></tr></thead><tfoot></tfoot><tbody id="j_id_6:dataTable_data" class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content"><tr data-ri="0" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">

<span class="idcol">20</span></div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span class="srccol">A</span></div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span class="dstcol">B</span></div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span class="sblcol">1-12345678909</span></div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span class="flwcol">9876543</span></div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span class="orddatecol">12/10/2013</span></div></td><td role="gridcell"><div class="ui-dt-c">
<span class="typcol">LOG</span>
</div></td><td role="gridcell" style="padding:0 0 0 0!important; margin:0 0 0 0!important;"><div class="ui-dt-c">
                <div style="padding:0 0 0 0!important; margin:0 0 0 0!important;"><div id="j_id_6:dataTable:0:containment" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width:350px; height:80px; margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0; white-space: pre; overflow: auto;"><div id="j_id_6:dataTable:0:containment_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content">  
                            RandomXML  
                    </div></div><script id="j_id_6:dataTable:0:containment_s" type="text/javascript"><!--
```

PrimeFaces.cw('Panel','widget_j_id_6_dataTable_0_containment',{id:'j_id_6:dataTable:0:containment'});
//-->

Cheers,

Alex

Comment: so every column has got fixed width, what happens when table is wider than the sum of all columns?

Comment: try setting the `.xmlcol {min-width: 300px; width: 30%}`

Comment: maybe you can try to look at generated html to identify the issue.

Comment: please do post the generated xhtml, but the first thing that comes to mind is that I would have tried with `width: xx%` instead of fixed pixels. The fixed width approach will bite you very soon.

Comment: @Alex If I understood you correctly, you want to get rid of the blank space on the right in the last column?

Comment: Kuba I prefer width: xx% but it seemed to make no difference, why I moved to pixels. You are correct in thinking I'm trying to remove whitespace on right of last column. I will post the output html when available (We've got an issue with our oracle DB now!)

Comment: Hi @Kuba, tried setting .xmlcol{min-width: 300px; width: 30%} no joy I'm afraid

Comment: you'll need to adjust all the columns

Comment: Hi @Kuba, I removed all references to width and it seemed to solve the problem. I know it's not an ideal solution but it works. Cheers for your help anyway :)